# Laravel - How to translate webpack Javascript files?

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-localization

So in standard blade templates, you can translate any text by encapsulating them

```
{{__("Hello")}}
```

and it will translate to the applicable locale.
You can also do this in any included Javascript in the file...

```
@section('footer-scripts')
@parent
<script type="text/javascript">
swal.fire({
    "title": "{{__('Alert')}}",
    "text": "{{__('The application has been successfully submitted!')}}",
    "type": "success",
    "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary"
});
<script>
```

But what if you have a global js file thats included via webpack, call it `custom.js` and within it, it too has wording that needs to be translated?

```
const {mix} = require('laravel-mix');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.copy('node_modules/tinymce/skins', 'public/js/skins');

mix.styles([
        'node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.css', //ApexCharts
        'resources/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css',
        'resources/assets/plugins/global/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.css',
        'resources/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.css',
        'resources/assets/css/pages/wizard/wizard-1.css',
        'resources/assets/css/style.bundle.css',
        'resources/assets/css/skins/header/base/light.css',
        'resources/assets/css/skins/header/menu/light.css',
        'resources/assets/css/skins/brand/dark.css',
        'resources/assets/css/skins/aside/dark.css',
        'resources/custom.css'
], 'public/css/libs.css');

mix.scripts([
    //Global - All Pages
    'resources/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js',
    'resources/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js',
    // Page Vendors
    'resources/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js',
    'resources/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/plugin-intl.js',
    'resources/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/accent-neutralise.js', // DataTables Accent neutralise
    // Custom Vendors
    'node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js', //ApexCharts
    'node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js',
    'node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js',
    // Custom
    'resources/custom.js'
], 'public/js/libs.js');
```